# how to cross apply if left outer join is true

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table called serviceEntry and table Called ServiceEntryPart which has a one to many relationship with the later. The problem is I want to cross apply only if the left outer statement is true.

So if I pass a part id and a service type id, it should only retun records where there is a true match, whats happeneing is if pass a partid and a service type id which did not exist for the specific record which has the part, I am getting results which did not have the part id passes but the records which contained the service type.  If I pass the correct service type for the part then I get correct results.

```
ServiceEntry
ID
XYZ
XYZ

ServiceEntrPart    Sample Data
ID                 1
ServiceEntrID      10
ServiceEntryPart   1,2,3

   IF (@SelectedSystemIDs = '')                        
      begin        
          SET @SelectedSystemIDs = NULL         
      END         

IF (@SelectedPartsIDs = '')                        
  begin        
      SET @SelectedPartsIDs = NULL         
  END         

IF(@UserRoleID = 1)    
 BEGIN     
  SET @PlatformID = 1     
  END  

IF(@UserRoleID = 2)  
BEGIN  
SET @PlatformID = 2  
END  

IF (@UserRoleID = 3)    
BEGIN    
SET @PlatformID = 12    
END   

IF(@UserRoleID = 4)
BEGIN 
SET @PlatformID = 3
END

IF(@UserRoleID = 5)
BEGIN 
SET @PlatformID = 4
END

IF(@UserRoleID = 6)
BEGIN 
SET @PlatformID = NULL
END
--SET @Reconciled = 'R'

IF(@Reconciled='R')                            
 set @ReconciledValue=1                            
ELSE IF(@Reconciled='N')                            
 set @ReconciledValue=0   
ELSE IF(@Reconciled = 'A')
 set @ReconciledValue = null                         

--SET @ServiceTypes = '9'

IF @ServiceTypes = ''                        
  SET @ServiceTypes = NULL                          

IF @ServiceTypes IS NULL                   
  SET @flag = 2                  
 ELSE                    
 set @flag = 100                  

 IF (@SelectedSystemIDs = '')                    
    begin    
      SET @SelectedSystemIDs = NULL     
    END  

  Select     
   se.ID as ServiceEntryID,    
   se.ServiceDateTime,
   se.ReasonForFailure,
   se.ActionTaken,
   se.VerificationPerformed,
   se.TSBNumber,
   se.ISANumber,
   (SELECT     
  CAST(ID AS varchar(6)) + ' ~ ' + PartDescriptionWithParent FROM [RunLogTest].[dbo].[Part]       
    where id= sep.PartID) as PartDescriptionWithParent ,       
   (SELECT SystemFullName from System WHERE ID=se.SystemID
   )as SystemName,    
   se.Reconciled,
   se.CreatedDate,
   se.ClosedDate,
   se.UpdatedDate,
   se.ServiceHours,
   se.ServiceMinutes     
   FROM     
   [ServiceEntry] se left outer JOIN  
   ServiceEntryPart sep  ON se.ID = sep.ServiceEntryID   
   INNER JOIN SystemModule ON sep.SystemModuleID = SystemModule.ID  
   INNER JOIN System ON SystemModule.SystemID = System.ID 
   CROSS apply
   dbo.SplitStrings_Moden(sep.ServiceTypeIDs, N',') M2
   JOIN  dbo.SplitStrings_Moden(@ServiceTypes, N',') P ON (M2.Item = P.Item   or @ServiceTypes IS NULL)
   where se.ID=ServiceEntryID AND (se.Active = 1)
   AND (@ReconciledValue IS NULL OR se.Reconciled = @ReconciledValue)
   AND (@SelectedSystemIDs IS NULL OR  se.SystemID IN(select  * from dbo.SplitInts_RBAR_1(@SelectedSystemIDs, ',')))
   AND (@SelectedPartsIDs IS NULL or sep.PartID IN(select * from dbo.SplitInts_RBAR_1(@SelectedPartsIDs, ',')))
   AND (se.ServiceDateTime between @StartDate and @EndDate)
   AND ((@PlatformID IS NULL) OR  (System.PlatformID = @PlatformID) OR (@PlatformID = 12 AND System.PlatformID <= 2))  
   order by se.CreatedDate desc
```

Comment: Be careful with inner joins after a left join...you left join se to sep, and then inner join systemmodule on sep = systemmodule.  A record in se lefts join to sep and nothing is found results in a null for all sep fields.  If you inner join that null sep value to another table, it will drop the record as per standard inner join rules.  Both of your inner joins that follow the left join should be left joins if you want to your null sep records in the results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without any ability to test this I would propose 2 methods, one is rarely used so you might want to ignore it.

You form an outer join between `se` and `sep`, so to retain that outer join relationship you need to ensure anything joining to `sep` also permits the outer join. That would require more left joins, and an outer apply, like this:

```
-- common approach
FROM [ServiceEntry] se
      LEFT OUTER JOIN ServiceEntryPart sep
                  ON se.ID = sep.ServiceEntryID
      LEFT OUTER JOIN JOIN SystemModule
                  ON sep.SystemModuleID = SystemModule.ID
      LEFT OUTER JOIN JOIN System
                  ON SystemModule.SystemID = System.ID
      OUTER APPLY dbo.SplitStrings_Moden(sep.ServiceTypeIDs, N',') M2
      LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.SplitStrings_Moden(@ServiceTypes, N',') P
                  ON (M2.Item = P.Item OR @ServiceTypes IS NULL)
```

OR (untested!) you can use a less used approach which involves moving the sequence of ON statements. What this does is changes the precedence of operation, and here I have shown brackets to highlight this. In effect the joins inside the brackets are performed to construct a `derived table` THEN that is outer joined to `se`

```
-- much less common           
FROM [ServiceEntry] se
      LEFT OUTER JOIN ServiceEntryPart sep
              (
                  INNER JOIN SystemModule
                              ON sep.SystemModuleID = SystemModule.ID
                  INNER JOIN System
                              ON SystemModule.SystemID = System.ID
                  CROSS APPLY dbo.SplitStrings_Moden(sep.ServiceTypeIDs, N',') M2
                  JOIN dbo.SplitStrings_Moden(@ServiceTypes, N',') P
                              ON (M2.Item = P.Item OR @ServiceTypes IS NULL)
              )
              ON se.ID = sep.ServiceEntryID
```

Whilst I believe either will work the first option is probably the most maintainable as it is easier for most folks to grasp.

However, do note that there is a condition in your where clause that would invalidate all outer joins **IF** @SelectedPartsIDs is not null:

```
  AND (@SelectedPartsIDs IS NULL
        OR sep.PartID IN (
              SELECT * FROM dbo.SplitInts_RBAR_1(@SelectedPartsIDs, ',')
                         )
      )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
...
FROM dbo.[ServiceEntry] se
    left outer JOIN (
        dbo.ServiceEntryPart sep
        CROSS apply dbo.SplitStrings_Moden(sep.ServiceTypeIDs, N',') M2
    ) ON se.ID = sep.ServiceEntryID
...
```